# Remix.run: Cookie is null in loader even though it exists

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I have a separate Elixir / Phoenix backend that sets the cookie properly upon logging in before redirecting to my remix app:

```
    conn
    |> put_resp_cookie("x-auth-token", %{jobseeker_id: generated_user.id},
      path: "/",
      max_age: one_week,
      http_only: true,
      secure: true,
      same_site: "strict",
      domain: "localhost",
      sign: true
    )
    |> redirect(external: "http://localhost:3000/profile")
```

On my `/profile` route component, I have this loader

```
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
  const cookieHeader = request.headers.get('Cookie');
  console.log('cccccccccccccc', cookieHeader); // <------- prints cccccccccccccc null

  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND_URL!}/api/v1/me`, {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      ...(cookieHeader ? { Cookie: cookieHeader } : {}),
    },
  });
  const { data } = (await response.json()) as { data: Jobseeker };
  return json({
    jobseeker: data,
  });
};
```

However, when remix loads the `/profile` page, `request.headers.get("Cookie")` returns nothing even though the cookie is there.

[image]

This is what appears when I print `request.headers`:

```
{
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
  'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
```

Only upon refreshing does it returns a value and finally prints `cccccccccccccc x-auth-token=SFMyNTY.g2gDdAAAAAF3DGpvYnNlZWtlcl9pZGEBbgYAsWUCzYwBYgAJOoA.MP7RbWWaxgfy_QkqjQlpbYmSxDYyXqoNudZqjUOqENs`

[image]

And the new `request.headers` that includes `cookie`:

```
{
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  cookie: 'x-auth-token=SFMyNTY.g2gDdAAAAAF3DGpvYnNlZWtlcl9pZGEBbgYA8_4dzYwBYgAJOoA.Gta1vseP3eKCGE09OBZwU0RzgwlmvUy6XxaB__bibmc',
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  purpose: 'prefetch',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
  'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
  'sec-purpose': 'prefetch;prerender',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
```

This is happening on prod too over HTTPS. How can I fix this?

UPDATE 1:
One workaround that I discovered is redirecting to a new `/login_success` route, which I use to do a complete page refresh using `window.location.href = "/profile"`. Remix for some reason does not detect the new cookie unless I completely refresh. `redirect` did not work

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Index({}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.location.href = '/profile';
  }, []);

  return <div className="flex flex-col w-full">Please wait...</div>;
}
```